# How can I remove digits from these strings?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a text file containing a few string values:

```
PIZZA_123
CHEESE_PIZZA_785
CHEESE_PANEER_PIZZA_256
```

I need to remove the numeric values in these values and need the following output. The tricky part for me is that these numeric values are random every time. I need to remove these numeric values and write the string values alone to a file.

```
CHEESE_PIZZA
CHEESE_PANEER_PIZZA
```

What is an easy way to do this?

Comment: On SO, we do encourage users to post their efforts which they have put to solve their own problems, kindly do add that in your post.

Comment: Are the numbers always three digits long?

Comment: PIZZA_123 is deleted completely and the last underscore is also deleted. What do you want with `123_a4_5rrr` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/_[0-9]*$//' file > file2
```

Will do it.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it.  For example, since the numbers always seem to be in the last field, we can just `cut` off the last field with a little help from the  `rev` util.  Suppose the input is *pizza.txt*:

```
rev pizza.txt | cut -d _ -f 2- | rev
```

Since this uses two utils and two pipes, it's *not* more efficient than `sed`.  The sole advantage for students is that *regex* isn't necessary -- the only text needed is the `_` as a field separator.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below script for this.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

V1=PIZZA_123
V2=CHEESE_PIZZA_785
V3=CHEESE_PANEER_PIZZA_256

IFS=0123456789

echo $V1>tem.txt
echo $V2>>tem.txt
echo $V3>>tem.txt
echo "here are the values:"

sed 's/...$//' tem.txt

rm -rf tem.txt
```